# How to integrate an OpenMV H7 Plus optical flow camera with a flight controller running PX4?

Tags: integration, ros, px4, openmv

I've having some difficulty getting my flight controller (HolyBro Durandal) to read data from my OpenMV optical flow camera.

I'm using optical flow because I want to operate my drone in a GPS denied environment. Flight controllers need position data to operate and an optical flow camera is the most common alternative other than a GPS module.

There appears to be a integration instructions for ArduPilot - https://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/common-openmv-optflow.html - but unfortunately there's nothing for PX4.

I have the camera connected to one of my flight controllers telemetry ports. I know some of the FC setting needs amended to allow the FC to understand the optical flow data but I'm unsure which ones.
The end goal is for MavROS to understand this data and publish the /mavros/local_position/pose message.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Patrick

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem? I am interested in openMV cameras and was wondering how easy is to integrate them.

Comment: I'm afraid not but if you contact the px4 dev team they will be able to help.
The weekly dev call can be found here: https://docs.px4.io/main/en/contribute/dev_call.html